# Wordpress:Display A specific Header for a Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying To have No header for My Landing Page,but a sticky nav Bar On the header for the rest of my pages.

I edited the header(header.php),but it gets applied to all the pages.I would like The header To not show on the landing page.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

/*
 * Header Section of Iconic One
 *
* Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
*
* @package WordPress - Themonic Framework
* @subpackage Iconic_One
 * @since Iconic One 1.0
* /
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE     versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'themonic_logo' ) ) : ?>

    <div class="themonic-logo">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'themonic_logo' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"></a>
    </div>
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'iconic_one_social_activate' ) == '1') { ?>    
    <div class="socialmedia">
    <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'twitter_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter"/></a> <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'facebook_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/facebook.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook"/></a> <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'plus_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" rel="author" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/gplus.png" alt="Follow us on Google Plus"/></a><a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'rss_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/rss.png" alt="Subscribe RSS"/></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>  

    <?php else : ?>
    <hgroup>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
            <br .../> <a class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a>
    </hgroup>
<?php if( get_theme_mod( 'iconic_one_social_activate' ) == '1') { ?>
    <div class="socialmedia">
    <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'twitter_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter"/></a> <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'facebook_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/facebook.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook"/></a> <a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'plus_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" rel="author" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/gplus.png" alt="Follow us on Google Plus"/></a><a href="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'rss_url', 'default_value' ); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/rss.png" alt="Follow us on rss"/></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>  
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->

<div id="main" class="wrapper">
```

I have removed The nav bar on this File,But i wish to use the nav bar on all my other pages.
I tried the IS page() function,but it Does not work,for me at least.Could someone provide an example on how this should be done

Comment: Any general idea would be helpful,i've done some research,but Would like some affirmation on how to proceed

Comment: why don't you just make a custom page-type, which doesn't make a call to include the header? (i.e. don't put <?php get_header(); ?> at the top of said page). use the custom page type for this landing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create static "template page",

your first one would be your home page.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Homepage */?>
<?php get_header();?>
-- BODY HERE --
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Now you create how many pages you got like this, Home, About, Service, Profile, Contact.

Now you don't need a template for every single page but it wouldn't hurt I would recommend doing that.

Finally to get the different header for other page you just create a different header-other.php and use it instead of the header.php....

Make sure you use -name.php because you will call it like this on the page you want.

```
<?php get_header('name');?>
```

so anything past the - you put in here and WordPress will know that you are trying to use that HEADER.

I hope this helps and solves all your issues, best of luck with your project.